# "Человек, слепо верящий в свою непогрешимость, свой светлейший ум(,) наконец..."

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Интересует запятая при вводном (вводном ли?) "наконец". Что-то мозолит мне глаз и с ней, и без неё...

***Человек, слепо верящий в свою непогрешимость, удачу, знание законов экономики, свой светлейший ум(,) наконец, — потенциальный клиент Лисы Алисы и Кота Базилио.***

Фразу вопреки своему обыкновению даю полностью, адаптация может сказаться на понимании. Но прошу особо не влезать в смысл, в источнике, там где я её написал, контекст вполне допускает подобные "размышлизмы".

***UPD*** - запятая после "законов" выглядела технический брак, хотя я уже не помню, как именно фраза звучала в оригинале. Исправил. Остальное - в силе.

Comment: Мне кажется, что правильно писать _лиса_ Алиса и _кот_ Базилио. "По дороге домой Буратино встречает двух нищих – кота Базилио и лису Алису". http://narodstory.net/skazki-tolstoy.php?id=1   "С утра Буратино побежал домой, но по дороге повстречался с двумя мошенниками — лисой Алисой и котом Базилио". https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA,_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%91%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова - Спасибо, я не хочу на этом заострять внимание.  Во-первых спороно (помнится, раньше и в оригинальном тексте писали с заглавной), во-вторых, у меня-то это имена собственные.

Comment: @shampar, мне не нравится ваша правка. От слова "совсем". Зачем содержательній заголовок менять на безликую общую фразу?

Comment: Вы пишете (так было и раньше) по месту темы вопроса цитату на полторы-две строки, потом её же повторяете в тексте вопроса. Теперь же просите ещё и «особо не влезать в смысл». Это тоже не нравится,  и те, кто составлял рекомендации относительно желательной краткости и однозначности вопросов, наверное, этот случай и имели в виду. Или что-то другое?

Comment: @shampar текст этот - мой, поэтому я и говорю, что именно мне не нравится в вашей редактуре. Что не нравится другим - можно высказать другим образом, не ломая столько дров. А что до заголовка, так он более отвечает требованиям отражать в нем существо вопроса, а не безликое правило. Насчет не вникать в смысл - да, я настаиваю на том, что вопрос чисто пунктуационный. Неоднократно сталкивался, что в подобных случаях (не только у меня) начинается обсуждение "а чо автор хотел сказать" и "а давайте поменяем фразу". По счастью, здесь никому пока не пришло в голову подобное. Кроме Вас.

Comment: Ваши фразы не менял, пришло в голову не мне. И не мне судить чьи-то тексты, тем более без указания авторства. Правило в вопрос не внедрял. Перестаньте на меня шептать!

Answer (score 1):

1. Для начала я бы, собственно, исправила **само** предложение.
   Верящий (**во что?**):
   в свою непогрешимость,
   [в] удачу,
   **[в] знание законов, экономики...**

Должно быть так (во избежание рассогласования):
или  — [в] **знание законов и** [в знание] **экономики**;
или  — [в] **знание законов экономики**;
или  — [в] **знание законов**, [в] **экономику**.

2. Добавила бы перед каждым "перечислительным" членом предлог **в** — для лучшего восприятия смысла предложения.
3. И вот тогда, как мне кажется, слово **наконец** является вводным, потому что — вкупе *со слепо верящий* и *светлейший ум* — дает последнюю (и отчасти саркастическую) оценку сказанному.

**Человек, слепо верящий в свою непогрешимость, в удачу, в знание законов экономики, в свой светлейший ум, наконец, — потенциальный клиент Лисы Алисы и Кота Базилио.**

[НАКОНЕЦ, вводное слово](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_436)

Answer (score 0):

*Наконец* может быть или наречием, или вводным словом. Тут явно не наречие. Значит, вводное слово. Значит, запятая нужна.

Может, объясните, что заставляет Вас сомневаться?

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86&all=x

Comment: Дык... Именно то, что для меня свсем не "явно не наречие". Вы по сути просто переформулировали мой вопрос...   Вот из Кузнецова (по Вашей ссылке) *II. в зн. союза. (в сочет. с союзом и).Употр. при перечислении для присоединения слова или предложения, стоящими последними в ряду перечисляемых. Можно было приехать, написать письмо и наконец позвонить. **Она умна, мила, наконец хорошо воспитанна.*** Мне-то как раз хотелось бы обоснования, что здесь оно МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ вводным словом. Именно для того, что с запятой смотрится лучше, но я не вижу оснований.

Comment: Допустим, выступает в значении союза. Если "и наконец", то запятая не нужна. А без *и* запятая все равно нужна перед "наконец". И это не наречие, потому что не отвечает на вопросы наречий (где? когда? и т. п.) Неубедительно?

Comment: Ну посмотрите выделенное жирным в первом моем комментарии. Нет там "И". И запятой нету. М_Г, больше конструктива, в подобных ситуациях дедуктивный метод не очень работает. Наречие в роли союза или вводное.

Comment: Как вводное мне не нравится потому, что тут нет реального перечисления, завершения мысли...Как и в примере у Кузнецова.  Как наречие в обычной роли - понятно, нет значения подходящего ("наконец-то".- или чего-то подобного).  А вот в роли союза - да, по смыслу самое оно, но союз этот где-то абсолютном конце фразы... Тоже не кошерно как-то.